# Why this function doesn't rendering in react

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-redux

first, Thank you for entering like here

i want to be able to use like this code, this code is rendering in react component but second code doesn't work ..

That's what i worder sir.

```
    function forFourMultiplyFour(_pictures) {

        if (_pictures.length === 0) {
            return '';
        }

        return <div
            style={{ display: 'flex', justifyContent: 'center' }}>{_pictures.map((el) => {
                return <div style={{ margin: '5px' }}>
                    <Img key={el.id} src={el.src} alt="picture"></Img>
                    <div style={{ display: 'flex', justifyContent: 'space-between' }}>
                        <div>{el.title}</div>
                        <div>생성일자</div>
                    </div>
                </div>;
            })}</div>;
    }
```

```
    function makeHowManyPage(count) {
        // 태그안에 함수로 또 다른 태그를 감싼다음에 forFourMultiplyFour로 한 것처럼 렌더링할 것을 return 했는데
        // 안되서 state을 배열로 만들어서


        return <div
            className="makeHowManyPage"
            style={{ display: 'flex', justifyContent: 'center' }}>
            {() => {
                for (let i = 1; i <= count; i++) {
                    return <div>{i}</div>
                }
            }}
        </div>
    }
```

and then i do render like this

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import styled from 'styled-components';
import dummyPictures from '../../../dummyDate';

function Gallery() {

    const [forRenderingOne, setForRenderingOne] = useState(<div></div>);
    const [forRenderingTwo, setForRenderingTwo] = useState(<div></div>);
    const [forRenderingThree, setForRenderingThree] = useState(<div></div>);
    const [forRenderingFour, setForRenderingFour] = useState(<div></div>);
    const [pageCount, setPageCount] = useState(<div>1</div>);
    const [_temp, set_Temp] = useState(['안녕하세요', '안녕하세요', '안녕하세요', '안녕하세요'])

    // 애초에 4개씩 받아서 뿌릴 것

    function forFourMultiplyFour(_pictures) {

        if (_pictures.length === 0) {
            return '';
        }

        return <div
            style={{ display: 'flex', justifyContent: 'center' }}>{_pictures.map((el) => {
                return <div style={{ margin: '5px' }}>
                    <Img key={el.id} src={el.src} alt="picture"></Img>
                    <div style={{ display: 'flex', justifyContent: 'space-between' }}>
                        <div>{el.title}</div>
                        <div>생성일자</div>
                    </div>
                </div>;
            })}</div>;
    }

    function makeHowManyPage(count) {
        // 태그안에 함수로 또 다른 태그를 감싼다음에 forFourMultiplyFour로 한 것처럼 렌더링할 것을 return 했는데
        // 안되서 state을 배열로 만들어서


        return <div
            className="makeHowManyPage"
            style={{ display: 'flex', justifyContent: 'center' }}>
            {() => {
                for (let i = 1; i <= count; i++) {
                    return <div>{i}</div>
                }
            }}
        </div>
    }

    useEffect(() => {
        // 서버에서 줄때 무조건 객체 16개가 든 배열이 응답해와야 정상작동되는 코드다..
        setPageCount(makeHowManyPage(5))

        setForRenderingOne(forFourMultiplyFour(dummyPictures.pictures.slice(0, 4)));
        setForRenderingTwo(forFourMultiplyFour(dummyPictures.pictures.slice(4, 8)));
        setForRenderingThree(forFourMultiplyFour(dummyPictures.pictures.slice(8, 12)));
        setForRenderingFour(forFourMultiplyFour(dummyPictures.pictures.slice(12)));

    }, []);

    return (
        <div>
            {/* {forRenderingOne}
            {forRenderingTwo}
            {forRenderingThree}
            {forRenderingFour} */}
            
            {()=>{ return <div>'안녕하세요'</div>}}
        </div>
    )
}

export default Gallery

const Img = styled.img`
    width: 15vw;
    height: 20vh;
`
```

Comment: Components are not appropriate state values. State should be the most simple possible values that need to be saved so your component can render. The component has the responsibility of declaring what the UI should be, not the state.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As stated this code snippet not working,

```js
    function makeHowManyPage(count) {
        // 태그안에 함수로 또 다른 태그를 감싼다음에 forFourMultiplyFour로 한 것처럼 렌더링할 것을 return 했는데
        // 안되서 state을 배열로 만들어서


        return <div
            className="makeHowManyPage"
            style={{ display: 'flex', justifyContent: 'center' }}>
            {() => {
                for (let i = 1; i <= count; i++) {
                    return <div>{i}</div>
                }
            }}
        </div>
    }
```

Have a look at this snippet returning `div` not `array`,

```js
for (let i = 1; i <= count; i++) {
   return <div>{i}</div>
}
```

`map` works differently.

Consider changing this to,

```js
 function makeHowManyPage(count) {
    // 태그안에 함수로 또 다른 태그를 감싼다음에 forFourMultiplyFour로 한 것처럼 렌더링할 것을 return 했는데
    // 안되서 state을 배열로 만들어서

    let array = [];
    for (let i = 1; i <= count; i++) {
      array.push(<div key={i}>{i}</div>);
    }

    return (
      <div
        className="makeHowManyPage"
        style={{ display: "flex", justifyContent: "center" }}
      >
        {array}
      </div>
    );
  }
```

Then usage,

```js
export default function App() {
  
  // declaration

  let elements = makeHowManyPage(5);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Hello CodeSandbox</h1>
      {elements}
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand what you exactly wanted, I just write some code that I expected to solve your problem.
I hope it can help your problem though it is not the best solution.

First, I divide Gallery component into two components including your `forFourMultiplyFour` function.

(I don't have dummy pictures, so I used a picture list api for this.)

Second, as windowsill's comment, write simple value for the useState initial value. I think you only need two values, pages and images array.
Usually people get the image list changing page and offset value not slicing image array. (If I have a wrong idea, please let me know.)
So I just change page state when clicking button.

For 4*4 image arrangement, I used flex property.

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import axios from "axios";
import ForFourMultiplyFour from "./ForFourMultiplyFour";

function Gallery() {
  const [page, setPage] = useState(1);
  const [images, setImages] = useState([]);
  const URL = "https://picsum.photos/v2/list";
  const LIMIT = 16;

  useEffect(() => {
    async function fetchImages() {
      const { data } = await axios.get(`${URL}?page=${page}&limit=${LIMIT}`);
      setImages(data);
    }
    fetchImages();
  }, [images, page]);

  useEffect(() => {
    setPage(page)
  }, [page])

  return <ForFourMultiplyFour images={images} page={page} setPage={setPage} />;
}

export default Gallery;
```

```
import styled from "styled-components";

function ForFourMultiplyFour({ images, setPage, page }) {
  const handlePage = (param) => {
    if (param === "plus") {
      setPage(page + 1);
    } else {
      if (page === 1) return;
      setPage(page - 1);
    }
  };
  if (images.length < 1) return <></>;
  return (
    <>
      <ButtonWrapper>
        <Button onClick={() => handlePage("minus")}>prev</Button>
        <Button onClick={() => handlePage("plus")}>next</Button>
      </ButtonWrapper>
      <div
        style={{
          display: "flex",
          justifyContent: "center",
          flexWrap: "wrap"
        }}
      >
        {images.map((el) => {
          return (
            <div style={{ margin: "5px", flex: "1 1 20%" }} key={el.id}>
              <Img key={el.id} src={el.download_url} alt="picture"></Img>
              <div style={{ display: "flex", justifyContent: "space-between" }}>
                <div>생성일자</div>
              </div>
            </div>
          );
        })}
      </div>
    </>
  );
}

const Img = styled.img`
  width: 15vw;
  height: 20vh;
`;

const ButtonWrapper = styled.div`
  display: flex;
`;

const Button = styled.button`
  cursor: pointer;
`;

export default ForFourMultiplyFour;
```

You can see the result through [this Code Sandbox link](https://codesandbox.io/s/dry-voice-oir7h?file=/src/Gallery.jsx).

If it is not a solution that you wanted, please comment me. Then I'll try to help you using another solution.

Comment: Thank you answers for me! i can not use english as well as i appreciate

I am so sad what i can selete answer is one

Thank you so much!